# How to trigger a Jenkins build on a Perforce submit

Tags: jenkins, triggers, perforce, build-automation

I am using Jenkins with Perforce. I have downloaded the [P4 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin), and I have read over the documentation but I am still a bit confused. In my Jenkins project, I have the build trigger set to "Perforce triggered build". I'm assuming that means I need to add a trigger to Perforce that tells Jenkins to run a build, but I have no idea on how to do that.

I have not been able to find any documentation on how to implement a trigger from Perforce to notify Jenkins it needs to run. I can find documentation from Perforce on how to setup basic triggers, but I can not find anything from Jenkins on how to set up the actual connection to trigger builds on Perforce submits.

On the "Changes" tab in Jenkins, I am able to see the what was submitted to Perforce, so I know that Perforce and Jenkins are at least communicating. Initially, I thought that Jenkins would just automatically run the build on a Perforce submit, if I had "Perforce triggered build" checked, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So my questions are:

Am I correct in assuming that I need to manually create a trigger to be added to Perforce?

If so, does anyone know of any documentation or examples that I can look to as a guide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a trigger to Perforce. [It's well documented here.](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219152268-Use-POST-Commit-Hook-with-Perforce-Triggers)