# Can I automate builds without having acces to P4 server?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am trying to setup a jenkins server for the very first time. I have synced it to the Perforce server I use, and I have created a workspace for that. Now I would like jenkins to start building everytime a change is submited, I have been researching through the topics here, and I found this link: [How to trigger a Jenkins build on a Perforce submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233905/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-a-perforce-submit). But it mentions that in order to do that I have to create a script on the P4 server `On the Perforce server, it is possible to create triggers or, in other words, scripts to be run on a particular event - for example after a change-commit.`, I do not know what it means to create a script on the P4 server. Does it mean I need to have physical access to the server? I am just connecting to a remote server. I am kinda lost here...

Comment: How do you expect to trigger something off of what happens in a Perforce server if you don't have access to the Perforce server?

Comment: my bad, I explained me wrongly. I have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd have access to be able to create a trigger. If you *can't* do that, the next best thing is to create a cron job or scheduled task (depending on your OS) to check to see if there is something new. I've run similar jobs to:

1. Run *p4 sync -n* to see if there is anything new
2. If there is something new, a) sync it and build it (your choice of everything, or you could write something that would test, say, the first changelist for which there is something new, then keep doing so changelist-by-changelist)
3. If there is already a build in progress, don't run.

My jobs were set to check every five minutes, but I even had a project where once/hour was enough.